# How to Select Edit link dynamically based on "ng-binding" Category passing

Tags: angularjs, protractor

This is the code:

```
<div class="grid">
    <button type="button" ng-click="addProductCategory()">Add</button>
    <!-- ngRepeat: productCategory in productCategories --><div class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="productCategory in productCategories">
        <div>
            <p class="ng-binding">Category A</p>
        </div>


        <ul class="">
            <li>
                <a ng-click="updateProductCategory(productCategory, $event)" class="" href="#">Edit</a>
                <a ng-click="deleteProductCategory(productCategory, $event)" class="" href="#">Delete</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- end ngRepeat: productCategory in productCategories --><div class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="productCategory in productCategories">
        <div>
            <p class="ng-binding">Category B</p>
        </div>


        <ul class="">
            <li>
                <a ng-click="updateProductCategory(productCategory, $event)" class="" href="#">Edit</a>
                <a ng-click="deleteProductCategory(productCategory, $event)" class="" href="#">Delete</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- end ngRepeat: productCategory in productCategories --><div class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="productCategory in productCategories">
        <div>
            <p class="ng-binding">Category C</p>
        </div>


        <ul class="">
            <li>
                <a ng-click="updateProductCategory(productCategory, $event)" class="" href="#">Edit</a>
                <a ng-click="deleteProductCategory(productCategory, $event)" class="" href="#">Delete</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- end ngRepeat: productCategory in productCategories --><div class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="productCategory in productCategories">
        <div>
            <p class="ng-binding">Category D</p>
        </div>


        <ul class="">
            <li>
                <a ng-click="updateProductCategory(productCategory, $event)" class="" href="#">Edit</a>
                <a ng-click="deleteProductCategory(productCategory, $event)" class="" href="#">Delete</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- end ngRepeat: productCategory in productCategories --><div class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="productCategory in productCategories">
        <div>
            <p class="ng-binding">Category E</p>
        </div>


        <ul class="">
            <li>
                <a ng-click="updateProductCategory(productCategory, $event)" class="" href="#">Edit</a>
                <a ng-click="deleteProductCategory(productCategory, $event)" class="" href="#">Delete</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- end ngRepeat: productCategory in productCategories --><div class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="productCategory in productCategories">
        <div>
            <p class="ng-binding">Category N</p>
        </div>


        <ul class="">
            <li>
                <a ng-click="updateProductCategory(productCategory, $event)" class="" href="#">Edit</a>
                <a ng-click="deleteProductCategory(productCategory, $event)" class="" href="#">Delete</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- end ngRepeat: productCategory in productCategories -->

</div>
```

I could select an element by its position but what I'm trying is to select dynamically but didn't quite work, and the following is what i've got so far..

```
updateCatBtn: {  get: function() { return element(by.cssContainingText('div', 'Devices')).element(by.xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'Edit')])")); }},
```

and I tried this as well but couldn't get it worked..

```
updateCatBtn: {  get: function() { return element.all(by.binding('productCategory.name')).then(function(elements) {  elements.filter(function(cName) { cName.getText().then(function (text) {return text == Category D;}); }).then(function (m) {m.element(by.linkText('Edit')); }); }); }},
```

Could someone help me with this, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the category by text and then the [following](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following) `Edit` button:

```
//p[. = 'Category D']//following::a[. = 'Edit']
```